# Form submission canceled because the form is not connected in react js. Where am I going wrong?

Tags: reactjs

[image]  **This is a redeem Voucher form which I have created , based on the API response data. I have to make the states either true for success or false on failure, untill we get the api response, Loading snippet will be displayed.  **

Onclick of the avail subscription button, I'm not able to display the loading snippet. In the console it shows "Form submission canceled because the form is not connected ".

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import styles from './RedeemVoucher.module.scss'
import close from '../../../Assets/Images/close_grey.svg'
import verified from '../../../Assets/Images/verified.svg'

class RedeemVoucher extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            voucherNumber:'',
            pin:'',
            redeemVoucherForm:true,
            isLoading:false,
            error:false,
            verified:false
        }
    }
   
    handleUserInput =(e)=> {
        const name = e.target.name;
        const value = e.target.value;
        this.setState({ [name]: value.replace(/[-/+/?/./`/~/,/{/}/[!/|/@/#/$/%/^/&/*/(/)/_/>/</:/;/'/"/=A-Za-z]/g,"")});
      }
      handleSubscription=()=>{
        this.setState({
            isLoading:true,
            redeemVoucherForm:false,
            error:false,
            verified:false
        })
    }
    

    render() {
       
        return ( 
            <>
            {this.state.redeemVoucherForm ?
                <form className={styles.redeem_form}>
                    <img src={close} className={styles.close} onClick={this.props.close_RedeemVoucher_Prompt}/>
                    <p className={styles.head}>Redeem Voucher</p>
                    <p className={styles.description}>Enter your NCPA Membership Voucher details to avail your free subscription plan</p>
                        <label className={styles.voucher_number}>Voucher Number <span className={styles.star}>*</span></label>
                            <input 
                            type="text"
                            placeholder='Enter Voucher Number'
                            className={styles.voucher_number_box}
                            value={this.state.voucherNumber}
                            name='voucherNumber'
                            autoComplete="off"
                            onChange={(event) => this.handleUserInput(event)}
                            />
                        <label className={styles.pin}>Pin <span className={styles.star}>*</span></label>
                            <input
                            type="text"
                            placeholder="Enter Pin"
                            className={styles.pin_box}
                            value={this.state.pin}
                            autoComplete="off"
                            name='pin'
                            onChange={(event) => this.handleUserInput(event)}
                            />
                    <button className={styles.avail_subs} onClick={this.handleSubscription} disabled= {!this.state.voucherNumber || !this.state.pin} >Avail Subscription</button>        
                </form> 

                : this.state.isloading ?

                <div className={styles.loading}>
                    <p className={styles.verifying_info}>Verifying Information</p>
                    <p className={styles.please_wait}>Please Wait</p>
                    {/* loader */}
                    
                </div> 
                
                 : this.state.error ?
                 
                 <div className={styles.error}>
                     {/* API error response */}
                     <button className={styles.exit}>exit</button>
                 </div>
                 
                : this.state.verified ?
                
                <div className={styles.verified}>
                    <p className={styles.verifying_info}>Verifying Information</p>
                    <p className={styles.please_wait}>Please Wait</p>
                    <img src={verified} className={styles.verified_img} />
                </div>
                
                : null}
            </> )} 
            
    }


export default RedeemVoucher
```

Comment: Can you update your question to include the actual and complete console message? Is this an error? What is logging it? Also, from what I can tell, when you click the `Avail Subscription` button the `form` element is submitted and reloads the page.

Comment: I have updated the question with the error.

Comment: yet to integrate the api. i just want that state loading to show up. It is getting into that handleSubscription , the state is becoming true. but the loading div is not showing up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect your code is submitting the form and some default form actions are occurring. This is because `button` elements are of `type="submit"` by default when no `type` attribute is provided, and the `form` element has no `onSubmit` handler to prevent the default form actions from occurring. When the default form action occurs, generally the page will reload, this is likely wiping out your state update.

Explicitly declare the button to be `type="submit"` and move the `handleSubscription` callback to the `form` element's `onSubmit` handler. In `handleSubscription` prevent the default submit action.

```
handleSubscription = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();

  this.setState({
    isLoading: true,
    redeemVoucherForm: false,
    error: false,
    verified: false
  });
};

...

<form
  className={styles.redeem_form}
  onSubmit={handleSubscription}
>
  ...
  <button
    className={styles.avail_subs}
    disabled={!this.state.voucherNumber || !this.state.pin}
  > 
    Avail Subscription
  </button>        
</form>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you so much. the warning is gone now. but the snippet is not showing up. any idea on that?

Comment: @SritharniCN From what I can tell it looks like it should render something into the DOM when it hits that case. Have you examined the DOM in the browser's devtools to see what is actually rendered?

Comment: In setState , the voucherNumber and pin state is getting updated but isLoading is not becoming true and redeemVoucherForm remains true.

Comment: @SritharniCN You've a typo: `this.state.isloading` should be `this.state.isLoading` in the render in the ternaries. https://codesandbox.io/s/form-submission-canceled-because-the-form-is-not-connected-in-react-js-where-am-co05s